# Calculating complexity of logarithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, logarithm

As known the complexity to insert a node into AVL tree is `log(c)` when `c` is the number of nodes inside the tree.
I'm looking to insert m nodes into the tree so the complexity is:

`log(c)+log(c+1)+...+log(c+m)`

Any ideas/suggestions on how I can solve this and get Big-O?

Comment: What do u mean by `complexity of the following` ? If its literally the addition you are talking about, it seems like `O(m)`

Comment: why O(m)? if c=0 then its log(m!) which is O(m*log(m))

Comment: You question is either misleading or missing crucial details!

Comment: Please provide more context! The complexities are calculated of an algo.

Comment: Thanks! In my opinion the Big-O would be `O(NlogN)` where `N=m+c`

Comment: A loose upper bound would be O(m * log(c+m)) since you're inserting `m` nodes, and each insertion takes less than `log(c+m)` time.

Comment: @user3386109 So for sure it is not O(m) right?

Comment: @smith Yes, that's for sure. Even inserting `m` items into an empty tree (i.e. c=0) takes more than O(m) time, since each insertion (after the first) takes more than O(1) time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming c is not a constant:

```
log(c)+log(c+1)+...+log(c+m) = log(c * (c+1) * .... * (c+m))
                     = log((m+c)!/c!)
                     = log((m+c)!) - log(c!)
                     = O_theta((m+c)log(m+c)- clogc)
```

But for the sake of the Big-O complexities, we usually quote the loose-bounds: `O(NlogN)` where `N=m+c`